# JoinFormula: Migrating hbm to annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

We are converting all our hbm files to annotations and it's going well.
But we have problems with formulas.

There are 2 tables and 2 entities.

```
Table PERSON_TYPE
    SID      (number)
    CODE     (varchar2)

Table PERSON
    SID      (number)
    PERSON_B (boolean)

@Entity
Class PersonType
    @Id
    private Long sid;
    private String code;

@Entity
Class Person
    @Id
    private Long sid;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_B")
    private boolean personB;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula =
            @JoinFormula(value="(decode(PERSON_B, 1, "PersonType1", 'PersonType2'))", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
    })
    private PersonType personType;
```

We want to get Entity PersonType with a formula. When boolean personB is true, we want to have PersonType with CODE "PersonType1" otherwise we want PersonType with CODE "PersonType2".
After some attemps we have the above code but this give us following exception: "referencedColumnNames(CODE) of personType referencing PersonType not mapped to a single property".

It works when we use the sid (which is the primary key) instead of CODE in the formula, but we can not assume that we have them.